# Ошибка PHP 500 , internal server error 500

Tags: php, sql, apache, apache2

Ошибка PHP 500 , internal server error 500
Пре переходе на select.php
вылетает ошибка
[image: Та самая ошибка]

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP search</title>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    
#logo{

margin-left:300px;

}
#line{
    margin-left: 350px;
}   

</style>


<div id="logo">
<img src="phplogo.png" width="600" height="300">
</div>
<div id="line"> 
<form name="search_form" method="post">
<input type="search" name="search_line" size="70" placeholder="Write , What topic do you need ?">
<input type="submit" name="">
</form>
</div>

<?php

$search_result = $_POST['search_line']; //get data from input

if($search_result == ""){
    
    
    echo("Result:"+$search_result); //if user written down nothing 
}
elseif($search_result == "select" )
{
    
     
        header('Location : select.php');
     
}
else {
 echo "<h1>EMPTY  , repeat your request ,please</h1>";// if search input is empty 
 
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Причем , я посмотрел на ютубе  , там говорят только о хостингах .

Comment: Лучший совет для вас - откройте логи на сервере)

Comment: где  мне эти логи найти  и что править  ? максимально подробней ?

Comment: Кто же знает, как именно вы разворачивали свой Apache? Править пока ничего не нужно. как только вы найдёте `error.log` апача, вы найдёте в нём ошибку, из-за которой он отвечает `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: да ладно вам, товарищ намудрил что-то в `htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в вашем примере ошибочку `echo("Result:"+$search_result);` я могу предположить что это должно выглядеть таким образом `echo 'Result:' . $search_result;` либо `echo "Result: $search_result";`. Ошибка 500 конечно скорее всего не из-за этого. По идее должно вернуть `Warning: A non-numeric value encountered`. Ну и по поводу использования `header()`, я бы вам советовал почитать [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php), перед ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов.

По поводу отображения ошибок, есть разные способы:

**Включение вывода всех ошибок и предупреждений в файле php.ini**

error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On

**Включение вывода всех ошибок и предупреждений в коде PHP-скриптов
Включить вывод уведомлений и предупреждений можно, добавив в начало нужного .php файла следующие строки:**

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

**Включение вывода всех ошибок и предупреждений в файле .htaccess:**

php_value display_errors 1
php_value display_startup_errors 1
php_value error_reporting E_ALL